# using javascript variable inside the java function

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

wanted a solution on how to access the javascript variable inside the java scope.
In the below code, **<%=toppings[k]%>**
k is a javascript variable how can i access that, I am getting a message as k is **not known to JVM**

```
function value_transitAccountCounter(i){
    alert('welcome -->'+i);
    for(var k=0;k<5;k++){
        if(i==k){
            return '<%=toppings[k]%>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Java code is running *on the server*. Your JavaScript code is running *on the client*. So you can't use `k` on the server, it doesn't exist until the page is finished, sent to the browser, and the JavaScript therein executed.

From your code, it looks like you just need to access the strings stored in the server-side `toppings` array. You have two choices:

1. Output the entire `toppings` array to the page's script as a JavaScript array. Then you can just use it client-side.
2. Have your `value_transitAccountCounter` function make an [ajax call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to your server-side code, asking what the value of `toppings[i]` is. You'll need to change `value_transitAccountCounter` to accept a callback to use to return the value rather than actually returning it, because the ajax call will be asynchronous (`value_transitAccountCounter` will return before the ajax call completes and thus, before you have the value to return). (It's *possible* to make synchronous ajax calls, but it's a very, very bad idea and you're better off pretending it isn't possible. It completely locks up the UI of most browsers while the call is executing, *incredibly* irritating for users.)

Comment: @Crowder, if I use your first solution, do you see any further complications is involved for the server side manipulation

Comment: @harigm: Any time the array changes on the server, you'll need to send a new copy to the client (e.g., on page refresh or similar). Any changes you make the array client-side would naturally need to be sent to the server (via ajax, or in a form post, etc.).

Comment: @Crowder, Yes I understood your point, But in my application, I dont have to worry about that, since all the transactions are done before hand and all the values are stored in Array at Server side and I need to retrieve the data from server and display in the UI, Since the server array cant read in javascript so i am trying to copy that to page script array and populating using javascript, please suggest me if there is any better idea than this

Comment: @harigm: Without knowing the broader context, it's hard to recommend. But generally: If you need access to that data on the client, and it's not massive overhead to send it, then send it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a JavaScript variable from JSP. The JavaScript runs on the client side. The JSP runs on the server side. You could write something like this instead:

```
function value_transitAccountCounter(i) {
    alert('welcome -->'+i);
    <% for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) { %>
        if (i == <%= k %>) {
            return '<%= toppings[k] %>';
        }
    <% } %>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSP runs on the server. It outputs some content. The content is sent to the browser. The browser then executes code.

You **cannot** directly communicate between client side and server side code.

Since the JSP code runs *first*, it is easy to get data from the Java to the JavaScript (you just generate the JavaScript dynamically), however you want to go the other way.

In order to get data from a client side JavaScript variable to a server side JSP variable you must issue a new HTTP request by:

- Setting `location.href`
- Submitting a form
- Using `XMLHttpRequest`
- etc

The request needs to include the data you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Crowder is right:
you cannot intergrate your javascript in order to view java variable, but you can do the opposite, generally speaking, there is always a way to invert your problem in order to let your javascript code read java variable. Think about it.

Good luck